# AppBarLayout weirdly taking space & pushing content down

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-appbarlayout

I'm using the new Android Design Library & Auto hide of `Toolbar` feature. Currently the auto hide on scroll works fine. But the having this issue, take a look at screenshot below[image: Cutting of FloatingActionButton]

As you see the `FloatingActionButton` is **pushed bit down**.

Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
        style="@style/FabStyle"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

FabSyle:

```
<style name="FabStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom|end</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">@dimen/activity_vertical_margin</item>
    <item name="borderWidth">0dp</item>
    <item name="elevation">@dimen/fabElevation</item>
    <item name="pressedTranslationZ">@dimen/fabPressedZ</item>
</style>
```

I have also tried too add `margin` & `padding` bottom which works but when list is scrolled it goes too up.

Best thing is when I play with `AppBarLayout` which stops the auto hide on scroll for `Toolbar` then `FloatingActionButton` looks good.

Comment: Please also show us the `FabStyle` as it is the one that actually has all the layout parameters of the floating action button.

Comment: @LukaCiko Sure but there is not a issue with `FabStyle`. I identified `AppBarLayout` as bug source

Comment: @LukaCiko Did you got the issue?

Comment: Sorry, no. I suspect it's an issue with CoordinatorLayout because I've seen something similar.

Comment: @LukaCiko I guess it's an issue with design library not sure though

Answer (score 8):

`AppBarLayout` expects to be the first child of `CoordinatorLayout` to work correctly. [This article](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout) notes that:

> `AppBarLayout` currently expects to be the first child nested within a `CoordinatorLayout` according to the official [Google docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.html).

But apparently the docs have changed since then (maybe the restriction no longer applies? I'm not sure). Try moving your `AppBarLayout` to the first position like so:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
        style="@style/FabStyle"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you. Fixed a long pending visual glitch!

Comment: This saved me several hours of pulling out my hair ;)

Answer (score 3):

You need to change you FAB like this:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_shuffle"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/list"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    style="@style/FabStyle"/>
```

Comment: Interestingly it worked but I'm working for `Scroller` now

Comment: Any solution for `RecyclerView Scroller`

Comment: Instead of `RecyclerView` I'm using `FrameLayout` which is replaced with `RecyclerView` which contains `FloatingActionButton`

Answer (score 0):

for your RecyclerView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: I have my `SuperRecyclerView